# When is it really necessary to place Go source code in $GOPATH/src?

Tags: go, projects-and-solutions, directory-structure

Take a look at this shell session, where I build a simple hello world program in Go.

```
$ cd ~/lab/hello/
$ ls
hello.go
$ cat hello.go 
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
$ go build
$ ./hello 
hello, world
$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie)
Release:    8.7
Codename:   jessie
```

Here is what I don't understand. The tutorial at https://golang.org/doc/install#testing says that I should place my `hello.go` file at ~/go/src/hello. But I am not following this. How is my program compiling then? If my program is compiling fine in this manner, why does the documentation say that I should keep my source code at ~/go/src or $GOPATH/src when it does not seem to matter?

Is there a scenario where it is really necessary to place the source code at $GOPATH/src?

Comment: Try [creating a library](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Library).

Comment: Read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), it explains all of this.

Comment: @MadWombat is following the tested, validated, recommended way "something stupid"? If the designer of a machine tells you: "You must first press this button, then you can do X." would you also ask what evidence there is that it is better to press the button first? Is "the creator of the tool told you to do so" not evidence enough? Well, probably not where ego is as strong as in programming.

Comment: That's the thing. A programming language is not just a machine, it is a tool. And as a user of the tool I have to understand how it works, otherwise I cannot use it. So no, I am not going to just "press button X", I need to know exactly why I am doing this and what is going to happen.

And yes, forcing me to structure my source code using domain names as directory names is mind bogglingly stupid to the point of being insulting. Fortunately, vendor support takes some of the pain away.

Comment: @Volker You are missing the point of this question. This question is not about whether I should or should not follow what the documentation says.  This question is about what scenario would cause problems for me if I do not follow the documentation. That would help me to understand better the usefulness of following the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard Go tools look in the `$GOPATH` subdirectories `src`, `pkg`, and `bin`. For example,

`currency.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/text/currency"
)

func main() {
    t1799, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "1799-01-01")
    for it := currency.Query(currency.Date(t1799)); it.Next(); {
        from := ""
        if t, ok := it.From(); ok {
            from = t.Format("2006-01-01")
        }
        fmt.Printf("%v is used in %v since: %v\n", it.Unit(), it.Region(), from)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go build currency.go
currency.go:7:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/text/currency" in any of:
    /home/peter/go/src/golang.org/x/text/currency (from $GOROOT)
    /home/peter/gopath/src/golang.org/x/text/currency (from $GOPATH)
$
```

If we put the missing package in `$GOPATH/src`, the standard Go tools will find it.

```
$ go get golang.org/x/text/currency
$ go build currency.go
$ ./currency
GBP is used in GB since: 1694-07-07
GIP is used in GI since: 1713-01-01
USD is used in US since: 1792-01-01
$
```

Answer (score 3):

You *really* need to put your code in a `GOPATH` once you write more than a `package main`. When you `import "github.com/me/myapp/mylib"`, Go will look under your `GOPATH` for that. Tools like `go test` also work in terms of packages under `GOPATH`, not `.go` files.

It also becomes the more practical thing to do as soon as your code is in more than one file. It's like the difference between compiling your C program by directly invoking `cc`/`gcc`/etc. and using a tool like `make`.

If you're starting out and wondering why people want to break up projects into multiple packages in the first place, reasons include:

- Projects grow, and by 10K or 100K lines you really need to organize.
- Projects often turn out to contain reusable tools, and packages let other projects `import` them separately.
- Packages let you track and control what code has access to what other code and variables. For instance, private names in one package aren't accessible for other packages, so you know you can mess around with that private stuff without breaking code outside the package, and you know that no code outside is futzing with private fields/variables or calling private code behind your back.
- Packages minimize namespace collisions, i.e., you can have `gzip.Reader` and `io.Reader`. If you choose your names right, `packagename.ThingName` can make code read naturally.
- Packages can be recompiled, tested, etc. individually, which keeps your edit/build/test cycle faster.
- In Go specifically, packages enforce some other things about your code organization, like no cyclic dependencies (if A imports B, B doesn't directly or indirectly import A) and that packages under `/foo/internal/` only get used by packages under `/foo/`. Constraints like these can help keep a big project from ending up like tangled spaghetti.

There are other benefits but those should help show why it's worth getting in the habit. It's fine to just charge forward writing things in a big package for a little bit and start breaking up files moving some types, functions, etc. out into other packages as needed; the 'natural' boundaries will start to make more sense over time.

Answer (score 2):

As JimB says in his comment, the Go [documentation](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) makes this clear; basically, the GOPATH is *workspace* which allows you to keep all your project files and imports and artifacts in one location.

For a simple project it's not strictly necessary, but when you begin importing dependencies and want to manage libraries it becomes more helpful.